# Similar matrices if only difference is diagonalizable/non-diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

I am new to linear algebra, and am just looking for some feedback regarding the following solution:

True or false?

1.$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$$ and $$\begin{pmatrix}2&0\\0&-2\end{pmatrix}$$
are similar.

2.$$\begin{pmatrix}3&1&1\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$
and
$$\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&3\end{pmatrix}$$
are similar.

My answer to 1. is: false, because (amongst others) the determinants are different.
My answer to 2. is: false, because, despite the fact that the determinants, trace and rank are the same, the top matrix is diagonalizable, whereas the bottom one is not. Therefore they cannot be similar.

Comment: Yes..you are right.

Comment: @sunnyrathore
thank you!